# how to display more than one result data in select2 using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i am trying to display some field data from table mysql into the select2 option but whatever i do it still shows me only one. 
This is how I expected: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ppK.png)
Any suggestions? Thanks

in javascript file I have this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //List ajax for list product
  $(".js-productList").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "halaman/hal_search2ajax/productsList.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data){
        return { results: data };
      },
    cache: true
  },
  minimumInputLength: 3,
});
</script>
```

my code in html

```
<select name='item' class=\"js-productList form-control\" required></select>
```

Code in productList.php

```
    <?php 
// connect to database 
require('../../config/koneksi.php');

$q = $_POST['q'];

$sql = mysql_query("select id_item as id, item_name as text, item_code as code from item where item_name like '%".$q."%'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($num > 0){

    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        //I want to show the item_name and item_code
        $tmp[] = $data;

    }
} else $tmp = array();

echo json_encode($tmp);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. Seems to be the typical parse json.
I prefer tu use $.post:

```
 <select name='item' id="itemselect" class=\"js-productList form-control\" required></select>

var data = {
q: params.term // or the way you obtain them
}
$.post('halaman/hal_search2ajax/productsList.php', data, function(response) {
$.each(response,function(i,item){
$('#itemselect').append($('<option>', { 
    value: item.code, 
    text : item.code 
}));
}
}, 'json');
```

with append it understand what goes into value and the text

```
<option value="'+value+'">'+text+'</option>
```

Comment: i wanna show more text <option value="'+value+'">'+text1+'-'+text2+'</option>

Comment: The same. But you can add text: item.code, text2 : item.text, text3:item.id

Answer (score 1):

You just need to manipulate response return by ajax call using map() function

try like this

```
$(".js-productList").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "halaman/hal_search2ajax/productsList.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        q: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data){
        output = $.map(data, function (obj) {
                        obj.text = obj.text + "-" + obj.code
                        return obj;
                    });
        return { results: output };
      },
    cache: true
  },
  minimumInputLength: 3,
});
```

Here is working example https://jsfiddle.net/6tzkLtvL/2/

I hope it will help you.